# Parse "Inflation surge and asset prices to alter monetary policy"

Tags: meaning-in-context, infinitives, parsing

> “The recent minutes and speeches suggested that the FOMC (the Federal
> Open Market Committee) was not sufficiently concerned about **the
> inflation surge and asset prices to alter monetary policy** and that
> seems the most likely outcome from the testimony,” Steven Englander,
> global head of Group of 10 foreign-exchange strategy at Citigroup Inc.
> in New York, said in a report. “In consequence, the U.S. side will
> probably be USD negative and risk positive.”
>
> [Bloomberg News](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2014-07-12/dollar-falls-most-in-13-weeks-versus-yen-on-dovish-fed.html)

In this particular sentence, how does "to alter monetary policy" modify "the inflation surge and asset prices", in the deontic sense or the epistemic sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*to alter monetary policy* does not modify *the inflation surges and asset prices* at all. It is the complement of *sufficient*:

> ... not sufficiently concerned ... to alter monetary policy.

How concerned was the FOMC? —not so concerned that it felt that a change in monetary policy was called for.

In this context you must also be careful not to adopt the parsing *concerned ... to alter*, meaning “anxious to alter, desirous of altering”. That sense of *concerned* is forestalled by the prior presence of a complement to *concerned*, *about the inflation surge and asset prices*.

Comment: There is another grammar structure possible here, a rather clumsy one: 'about asset prices to alter monetary policy' meaning 'about the alteration of monetary policy by the asset prices', but the context suggests it's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

That was confusingly written. Normally this idea is expressed with "not concerned enough to" rather than "not sufficiently concerned to":

> the FOMC (the Federal Open Market Committee) was not concerned enough about the inflation surge and asset prices to alter monetary policy

I find it much clearer that way.